# flutter onClick delete image from firebase storage and firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I need on click delete image from firebase storage and firestore
I've written this code that does the delete from firestore only.

```
onLongPress: ()async{
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction myTransaction) async {
    await myTransaction.delete(snapshot.data!.docs[index].reference);
  });
},
```

screen from code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmJgy.png)

Comment: So did you consider also deleting the file from storage? https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/delete-files

Answer (score 0):

You can use
FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(url).delete()

like

```
onLongPress: ()async{
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction 
 myTransaction) async {
    FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('url')).delete()
    await myTransaction.delete(snapshot.data!.docs[index].reference);
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            DocumentSnapshot messages = snapshot
                                .data?.docs[index] as DocumentSnapshot<Object?>;
                            return ListTile(
                              subtitle: Text('From: ${messages['sender']}'),
                              title: Text('Text: ${messages['text']}'),
                              tileColor:
                                  selectedIndex == index ? Colors.blue : null,
                              onTap: () async {
                                setState(() {
                                  selectedIndex = index;
                                });

                                await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction(
                                    (Transaction myTransaction) async {
                                  await myTransaction.delete(snapshot
                                      .data!.docs[selectedIndex!].reference);
                                });
                              },
                            );
                          }));
```